# Unable to install Apache Ant

Tags: ant

i have downloaded the Apache Ant file "apache-ant-1.8.4-bin.zip" from the following link :- http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi.
then i have added an environment variable to my windows 7 operating system:-

```
Name = ANT_HOME Value = C:\
```

but when i typed the following using CMD command line:-

```
C:\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin>ant.bat
```

i got the following error: -

```
ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
```

So what might be going wrong?
BR

Answer (score 2):

Your ant home is:

```
C:\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\
```

Create environment variable ANT_HOME with this value. Don't forget to re-open cmd window after.

Answer (score 0):

Per Krestens answer, your ANT_HOME variable needs to be the base dir where ant was unzipped.  Then your PATH (either user or system) needs to add

%ANT_HOME%\bin;

That will allow you to call ant.bat (how ant starts on a windows system).